# How to target specific numbers and operators in arrayList's

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Rechnung  {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> operator = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<Integer> numbersInt = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void erklaerung() {
        System.out.println("Geben Sie '=' ein um das Ergebnis aufzurufen.");
    }

    public static void abfrage() {

        String ergebnis;

        System.out.println("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein: ");
        numbers.add(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Bitte entscheiden Sie sich für '+', '-', '/', '*', '=': ");
        ergebnis = scanner.nextLine();

        if (ergebnis.equals("=")) {
            for (String s : numbers)
                numbersInt.add(Integer.valueOf(s));

            System.out.println(numbersInt);
            System.out.println(operator);
        } else {
            operator.add(ergebnis);
            Rechnung.abfrage();
        }
    }
}
```

I have two String `ArrayLists` and I am able to convert the one of them to an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Now I want to take the first number of the integer list, get the operator the user enters and then add the second integer of the first list to fulfill the operation the user wanted.
For now without any mathematical laws like precedence etc.

How to I target specific operators and numbers and use them to calculate?

Comment: You probably want to switch from lists to LIFO collections for convenience. Just a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely have to use .equals to check what operator the user wants to use.

e.g.

```
if(ergebnis.equals("+")) {
     //Do Something
}
else if (ergebnis.equals("-")) {
     //Do Something
}
else if (ergebnis.equals("/")) {
    //Do Something
}
else if (ergebnis.equals("*")) {
    //Do Something
}
```

you could possibly make your different operators into seperate functions that accept two numbers as parameters.

Comment: This does work if I target only one operator from an input. But how do I target like the third operator from the arrayList? Thanks for contributing :)

Comment: As in arrayList.get(2)? Sorry im not 100% sure what you mean by this.